# Chaining multiple done() callbacks to the same deferred promise

Tags: jquery, promise

In short, I would like to have one general callback that always fires in case of a successful ajax call, followed by separate callback functionality depending on where the method is invoked.

This seems to work. My question is if this is a correct use of the promise object and if it's safe to assume that multiple promise callbacks of the same type always stack sequentially?

```
var dfd = $.Deferred(),
    promise = dfd.promise();

promise.done(function(){
    console.log(1);
}).done(function(){
    console.log(2);
});

dfd.resolve();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ax4nxbh/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a correct and documented use of the deferred object in jQuery. The documentation [clearly states](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/):

> Callbacks are executed in the order they were added.

It works differently in other promise libraries and generally `.then` is preferred to `.done` anyway (explained later in the answer). However given you're using jQuery promises it'll stack just fine sequentially if they're synchronous.

So the direct answer to your question is yes.

However, you can also do this with *asynchronous* code and have it chain better with `.then`:

```
promise.then(function(){
    console.log(1);
}).then(function(){
    console.log(2);
}).then(function(){
    return $.get(...);
}).then(function(){
    console.log(3); // this always executes after the $.get finishes.
});
```

Basically, `done` adds a handler and returns the same promise and `.then` returns a new promise chained from the last one. In general I'd only use `.done` to terminate chains and if you want to keep the return value (the argument of the `function(){`)

Comment: I was hoping that you would find this topic ;) When you say `generally .then is preferred to .done anyway` I suppose that you refer to chaining, and not `done` vs `then` in general? I guess the most suitable approach based on your comment would be to use `then()` followed by a "terminating" `done()`, even though I'm only dealing with synchronous code in this case?

Comment: @Johan in general I prefer `then` to `done` when using new promise libraries. In jQuery on the other hand using `.done` to terminate the chain is beneficial - so yes, then again that's not the biggest issue with jQuery promises.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for learning me the difference between the two!

Comment: What do you mean by "*it works differently in other promise libraries*"? Promises/A+ does specify to execute callbacks in the order of their `then()` calls as well. (waiting with my upvote till this is clarified :-)

Comment: @Bergi in jQuery `.done` takes a callback and returns the same promise. In other libraries like Q and Bluebird `.done` doesn't take anything and doesn't return anything. In jQuery it's used to chain handlers to the result - in other libraries in terminates the promise chain and logs any unhandled rejections - jQuery doesn't really handle rejections well in its promises. That's what I meant, I guess.

Comment: Ah, you mean "`done` works differently", not "sequence is different".